# Initialize Form Array With existing array in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have an dynamic array of department list fetched from server. I want to push that array to form array on initialization, basically i want to show checkboxes based on department name or id in array. I know how to push an empty array in reactive forms.but how to initialize with an existing array.Actually its an update/edit Component

```js
departmentList:any=[];    //array contains all departments  
SelectedDeptList:any=[];  //fetched from db , selected departments

userForm: FormGroup; 
this.userForm = this.fb.group({  //fb form builder
    'phone': [null],   
    'departmentList': this.fb.array([this.createDepartment()]),
})


createDepartment(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        'name': ''//checkbox value true or false
    });
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div formArrayName="departmentList" *ngFor="let item of 
userForm.get('departmentList').controls; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-md-6" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
                    <input formControlName="name" type="checkbox"> Department Name
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ToDo ?**

1. how can i populate or initialize list of all dept checkboxes and those should be true which are present or exist in my 'SelectedDeptList' array(fetched from db).

thanks in advance , any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

try this, prepare an array of object that contain selected and non selected element

```js
let departmentControl = <FormArray>this.userForm.controls.departmentList;

this.yourArray.forEach(department => {
  departmentControl.push(this.fb.group({name: department.name}))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This..

```
let departmentControl = this.form.get('departmentList') as FormArray).controls;
```

then when you receive response from server then do

I am assuming data in the form of array in data['departmentListdata']

```
data['departmentListdata'].forEach((department) => { this.departmentList.push(this.createDepartment(department)) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To pre-populate data, there are two methods of FormGroup instance. `setValue()` & `patchValue()`. After you receive the response from the server just set/patch the values using one of these methods `setValue()` and `patchValue()` both sets the value in `form control` of `FormGroup`.  `setValue()` sets the value for each and every form control of FormGroup. you cannot omit any form control in `setValue()` but if you want to assign only few form controls of FormGroup then you can use `patchValue().`

```
 UpdateForm(){
        this.userForm.setValue(
                 {
                    'phone' : '112345',//some Value
                   'departmentList': this.this.departmentList

                });
    }
```

OR use `patchValue()`. If you want to update a partcular formControl

```
  UpdateForm(){
            this.userForm.patchValue(
                     {

                       'departmentList': this.departmentList

                    });
        }
```

Comment: thanks for answer . patch value just patch those checkboxes that were selected and stored in db . but firstly before patch i would have to show all checkboxes then secondly patch value .